# Why use Hub.listen inside useEffect - Amplify Auth

Tags: authentication, aws-amplify

I'm looking through the documentation at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/#full-samples
and can't understand why Hub.listen is being used within use Effect.

```
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case 'signIn':
        case 'cognitoHostedUI':
          getUser().then(userData => setUser(userData));
          break;
      }
    });
```

If I'm creating an event listener why should I create in useEffect instead of in the main body of the function.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I was getting confused between functions and classes.
The `useEffect` with an empty array is being used to only create the event listener on initial render and not on subsequent renders.

Leaving the question up in case anyone else gets similarly confused

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with functions and classes. It is inside the `useEffect(() => {/*...*/}, [])` (note the empty dependency list) as it acts as the constructor of the component and is therefore only called once.

If `Hub.listen` is called inside the render function, this will result in growing list of event listeners, because everytime the component rerenders, a new listener is attached.

To keep you free from any memory issues, you would also detach a listener inside the `useEffect` hook. So for common listeners, would look like the following:

```js
const App = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = () => { console.log('foo'); }

        window.addEventListener('resize', listener);
       
        // destruct
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', listener)
        }
    }, []);
}
```